# C# program Time synchronization between Windows and linux

Tags: c#, windows, linux, synchronization

I want to add a function in my C# program that can synchronize the time between linux and windows, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to run an ntp server on the Linux server (many distributions either include one or make it easy to install), then use some sort of NTP client from within your program.  One approach to the .NET side is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1005/SNTP-Client-in-C), but instead of using a public time server, you would want to use the address of the Linux server.

Comment: I am pretty sure windows has built-in NTP support these days...

Comment: Well, yes... but that's not what the poster asked.  He asked how to add a function in his C# program.  I didn't say it was actually _necessary_ to do so, but the poster could have a good reason.